# I want View cover Button when View's parent layout is ConstraintLayout,but It's not the result I expect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Here's the code inner file activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="start"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="stop"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"/>         

  <View
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:background="#ff0000"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the preview:

[image: this is preview]

The Button is not covered.When I try replace the Button with TextView, The TextView is covered.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="start"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="stop"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />


  <View
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:background="#ff0000"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the preview:

[image: this is preview1]

No information is found on the Internet. Do I have to replace the Button with a TextView, Is there any other way?

Comment: Material design is a three-dimensional environment containing light, material, and cast shadows. 

So you need to add cast shadow in your `TextView` Like This..

android:elevation="1dp"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Button`s have a higher [`elevation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:elevation) than the `View` (and than the `TextView`). That's why it shows above the `View`, even when it should be drawn below by layout order.

See [Buttons](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-raised-buttons) definition in Material Design Guidelines:

> **Elevation**
>
> Flat buttons: 0dp
>
> Raised buttons: 2dp

And also the chapter on [Elevation & Shadows](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android).

So, you could set the `elevation` of the `View` to something above `2dp`:

```
<View
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this you need to set `android:elevation=""` to your `View` like below code

```
       <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="start"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:text="stop"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <View
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]