# Place ImageView on top of button in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

I'm facing issues with `constraintlayout` when placing `ImageView` or `FrameLayout` on top of a `Button`.

When i try to inflate a `fragment` on `FrameLayout`, Buttons that are part of activity are visible on top of fragment UI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47987945/3286819 Most likely your `Button` is over your `FrameLayout` because of elevation.

Comment: Hi .. What are you expecting as the result can you please specify?

Comment: Actually this frame layout is not on top of the button it's actually taking the entire screen

Comment: I mean FrameLayout must be over the button (should mask the button)

Comment: I found out that by default buttons will have an elevation of 2dp, so i elevated FrameLayout to 4dp, and my problem was solved

Answer (score 3):

> To place any view above another view you have to give **proper constraint** like below.
>
> Give top and bottom constraint proper and also as I give all constraint(start,end,top,bottom) to FrameLayout it's height and width give to 0dp(you can't use height to **match_parent** otherwise it's cover whole screen and overlap button).

[image]>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"/>
    
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

To set constraints of button and FrameLayout to,
 Button:

```
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

FrameLayout :

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok but if you want to tell 1 view to be above another  view in ConstraintLayout you can go to the design tab and move the higher above the lower view:

**Example:**

[image]

In the image, you can see that the button is placed below the frameLayout so he will be lower than the frameLayout (the frameLayout will be above the button)

---

**Also, you were missing some constraints on your button :**

```
  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout2" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

And if all that didn't help you check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987723/i-want-view-cover-button-when-views-parent-layout-is-constraintlayout-but-its/47987945#47987945), as *@Xavier Rubio Jansana* said, it may be because of elevation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="638dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/appGrey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```